# Error: A value of type 'AuthResult' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'FirebaseUser'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am working on a chat app and want to allow users to register using email and password. For some reason, I am getting the error below - is this implementation incorrect? I am not sure why i am getting "Error: A value of type 'AuthResult' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'FirebaseUser'."

```
class _RegistrationState extends State<Registration> {
  String email;
  String password;

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<void> registerUser() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createUserWithEmailAndPassword` returns `Future<AuthResult>`, you can check here:

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/lib/src/firebase_auth.dart#L91

To solve the issue do the following:

```
final FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    ))
        .user;
```

add the field `user` which is of type `FirebaseUser`